# How to think about this problem involving rotation about the line $x=y=z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, rotations

I'm trying to solve this problem from linear algebra:

> Consider a $120^{\circ}$ rotation around the axis $x = y = z$.
>
> $(a)$ Show that the vector $i = (1,0,0)$ is rotated to the vector $j = (0, 1, 0)$. (Similarly $j$ is rotated to $k = (0, 0, 1)$ and $k$ is
> rotated to $i$.) How is $j − i$ related to the vector $(1, 1, 1)$
> along the axis?
>
> $(b)$ Find the matrix $A$ that produces this rotation. Explain why
> $A^3 = I$. What are the eigenvalues of $A$?

I haven't been taught about rotation matrices (apart from the $2D$ case), and I'm not sure how to think about rotation from an arbitrary axis. This is what I've tried so far:

$(a)$ If $A$ is the rotation matrix, then $Ai = j$ is what I need to prove. But I have no idea on how to come up with $A$. I can see that $j - i = (-1, 1, 0)$ is orthogonal to the vector $(1, 1, 1)$.

$(b)$ $A^3 = I$ because three subsequent transformations by $A$ will rotate a vector by $360^{\circ}$ and so bring it back to its original position. Again, not sure how to come up with eigenvalues since I can't construct $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix for a linear transformation can be found as the columns will be the vectors that your basis vectors end up at.

The columns of $A$ will be were $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$ land respenctively after the rotation. $\hat{i}$ ends up at $\hat{j}$, $\hat{j}$ ends up at $\hat{k}$, and $\hat{k}$ end up at $\hat{i}$.

So $A = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{j} & \hat{k} & \hat{i}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &1 \\ 
 1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$

You should be able to do the rest.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks! But one thing remains though; For this to work, one needs to show that $i$ goes to $j$, $j$ goes to $k$ and $k$ goes to $i$. How do I show this?

Comment: @TrainHeartnet, good question, you could try a change of basis, with your new basis being the vector (1,1,1), and pick two other orthonormal bases. Not too sure honestly though.